# Intent onPostExecute() AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask

Im running an `AsyncTask` in an inner class and once complete within the `onPostExecute()` I want to use an intent to pass values to another activity however I have two errors that im not sure how to fix.

The errors occur on the `setResult()` line at `RESULT_OK` and the `finish()` line explaining that these two actions cannot occur outside of an activity. How would i use this intent in the onPostExecute of the 'AsyncTask'?

Code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("jobs", jobStatus);
    intent.putExtra("requestsSent", requests);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: edit your question and explain your problem with clarity. also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: context is missing. Like ActivityName.finish();

Answer (score 1):

you need use Context of Activity class like following for finish method:

```
YourActivity.this.finish()
```

and RESULT_OK exists on activity class, so you need:

```
Activity.RESULT_OK
```

so your code must be like following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("jobs", jobStatus);
intent.putExtra("requestsSent", requests);
setResult( Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
YourActivity.this.finish()
```

Comment: activity.finish(); works fine but setResult is still giving me an error: "The method setResult(int, Intent) is undefined for the type AsyncTask"

Comment: @Dbucha01 that also belongs to the Activity class. Needs a context.

Comment: @Dbucha01 you need context for setResult too

Comment: i fixed it with the line activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent); Activity being the activity used within the asynctask constructor

Answer (score 0):

`setResult` and `finish()` are method of Activity class. You will need activity context for the same

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html.

Now pass the Activity context to the constructor of AsyncTask

```
 new TheTask(ActivityName.this).execute(params);
```

Then

```
Context mContext;
public TheTask(Context context)
{
     mContext = context;
}
```

If AsyncTask is an inner class of the Activity you can use `ActivityName.this`

```
  ((Activity) mContext).setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
  ((Activity) mContext).finish();
```